# Specify a form's record in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Typically in Ember, you declare a form without having to declare the record it's editing. For instance (using Emblem.js):

```
form
  input type="text" value=body
  button click="submit"
```

This works because you've specified the model to be edited in your route. What if the form doesn't have a route associated with it, though? In this case, the form is encapsulated within a component. Within the component, I've created the record and can access it in template as `comment`. However, if I try something like this:

```
form comment
  input type="text" value=body
  button click="submit"
```

Then Ember errors. Is there some syntax I don't know about? Something like `form record=comment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form itself has nothing to do with it.  It's the context of template at that point.  In your first example `body` is a property in scope in the template.

In your example the property isn't in the scope, but a property on the `comment` property.

In handlebars you can change the scope like so

```
{{#with comment}}
....
{{/with}}
```

In Emblem

```
 with comment
    form
      input type="text" value=body
      button click="submit"
```

Additionally if you don't need to change the scope, but just want to bind a property, you can do it like so

```
form
  input type="text" value=comment.body
  button click="submit"
```

Comment: Interesting. Using this approach, you could edit multiple records through a single form.